# A file doesn't exist but git thinks it does

Tags: git

How come?

```
git push origin master
......
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: fdsfdsfdsfds.....
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File some_file.so is 125.70 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to ...
```

But

```
ls some_file.so
ls: cannot access some_file.so: No such file or directory


$ git rm --cached some_file.so
fatal: pathspec 'some_file.so' did not match any files
```

Answer (score 3):

In all likelihood, you committed the file and then removed it in a later commit. GitHub rejects the commits where the file existed.

[GitHub has documentation on how to remove large files from existing commits.](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/#removing-a-file-added-in-an-older-commit)